# Have any children in Gaza starved to death as a result of the current war?

Tags: israel-hamas-war, gaza

[US Senator Chris Van Hollen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Van_Hollen) stated in [a speech](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=349817554627535):

> I asked the head of the World Food Programme, former American ambassador Cindy McCain about these reports. [...] I sent her a note asking about reports that some children have now crossed the awful threshold from being on the verge of starvation to dying of starvation. [...] She wrote back, and I quote:
> "This is true. We are unable to get in enough food to keep people from the brink. Famine is imminent. [...]"

Have any such deaths from starvation been confirmed?

Comment: These two Wikipedia articles: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip_famine) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_of_the_Israel–Hamas_war_on_children_in_the_Gaza_Strip) have what seems likely to be the most current and reliable information you could find on this topic.

Comment: @DanRomik thanks, it does seem that some newborns are starving, due to mothers being too malnourished to lactate and lack of formula.

Comment: You just give a quote and then ask if the claim is correct.   Is there any reason to believe it is false?  If there is one, why don't you add it to your post.

Comment: @KlausN no corroboration was forthcoming. Actually all the deaths from starvation that were suggested in the answers came from later.

Comment: I don't understand what your claim is.  From your post there is Chris van Hollen that claims that there are reports and asks Cindy McCain about these reports.  She doesn't seem to answer the precise question that Van Hollen is asking.  So is your claim that the reports Van Hollen is talking about do not exist? Or that such reports exist but that no children have died from starvation?  In the later case, wouldn't it make more sense to quote the reports (instead of Van Hollen) and then claim that these reports are wrong? (Maybe you are not actually claiming that the reports are wrong...)

Comment: If you are interested in a specific timeline, maybe you should add this in your post "Were there any confirmed deaths from starvation in Gaza at the moment that Van Hollen wrote to McCain on February XXX?" for example? or "at the moment that Van Hollen gave his speech" ?

Comment: @KlausN it is unclear what reports Van Hollen was referring to (and which McCain seemed to confirm). I think both the question (unresolved) of whether anyone had starved to death by the time of Van Hollen's statement and the question of whether anyone has starved to death in general (seemingly resolved) are of interest here.

Comment: New information indicates 'yes'. See my answer below.

Answer (score 23):

##### The conditions for starvation exist.

It is hard to find accurate information about what is happening in Gaza, and particularly in northern Gaza under strict IDF control.  However numerous reliable sources have been describing the food situation as critical for some time.

- As early as December, the UN World Food Program said 90% of people could not eat every day, as reported by the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-67670679)
- On 16th January, the UN Office of the High Commissioner on Human Rights [said](https://www.ohchr.org/en/press-releases/2024/01/over-one-hundred-days-war-israel-destroying-gazas-food-system-and) that "Israel [is] destroying Gaza’s food system". They give some statistics, including 335,000 children under 5 at high risk of severe malnutrition and stunting (stunting means irreversible physical or cognative damage from malnutrition at this critical age).
- By 20th February, the World Food Program had [suspended](https://www.wfp.org/news/un-food-agency-pauses-deliveries-north-gaza) deliveries to the north of Gaza. As the level of starvation rises, food shipments need police protection to ensure fair distribution. But the IDF refuses to stop killing police/security officers protecting food deliveries, as they consider them part of Hamas, as reported by the [Times of Israel](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/2/25/two-month-old-palestinian-boy-dies-of-hunger-amid-israels-war-on-gaza)

##### There are unconfirmed reports of children starving to death.

An example of a child dying from starvation would be Mahmoud Fatouh, a two month old infant who died shortly after arriving at the Al-Shifa Medical Complex. This has been widely reported by reputable news agencies such as the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-68398476), and in more detail by less impartial but generally reliable ones like [Al Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/2/25/two-month-old-palestinian-boy-dies-of-hunger-amid-israels-war-on-gaza) who claim to have a video. The BBC report it as "... says Dr Amjad Aliwa" rather than putting it as fact in their article, because they insist on a high level of corroboration before they report something as fact.

##### Children have almost certainly starved to death.

Taken together, the above two points provide fairly strong evidence that children, particularly the very young, are starving to death.  The nature of the war is that firm numbers, or even confirmation of specific cases will probably not be available until the conflict is over, so this is the closest thing to proof we can expect to find at this time.

Comment: Israel [disagrees](https://www.foxnews.com/world/israel-rejects-un-aid-agencies-criticism-gaza-on-brink-starvation-no-shortage-of-food) (or at least it did a month ago): "Israel rejects UN, aid agencies criticism that Gaza is on brink of starvation: 'no shortage of food'. [...] If you open Telegram and other social media pages, take a look at the marketplace in Rafah last Friday – you will see that while many things are missing, there is no shortage of food."

Comment: Even out of wartime breastfeeding can be difficult and formula sometimes hard to find. You would expect a war to make this much more difficult. The death of Mahmoud Fatouh is plausible and reasonably well sourced by the BBC, so I wouldn't doubt it. So this is a pretty good answer to the question as I asked it. I'm not sure this case quite attests to full-fledged famine conditions in the way that the starvation of an older child would.

Comment: Beside the point I think, but Al Jazeera is not "generally reliable" when it comes to Israel-Palestine.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat That does not necessarily reflect the current situation in northern Gaza. a) Rafah is right next to the Egyptian border, which is the border aid is coming in over, b) Although the IDF has conducted airstrikes and limited raids on Rafah, they don't have a regular presence there, so aid is still being delivered and c) a month is a long time in Gaza

Comment: @Colin AJ is not as good as the BBC, and they have a strong pro-Arab slant on international relations and especially the Palestine conflicts. But this mostly appears in the form of opinion pieces which are labelled as such, and a bias in what they do and don't report, and the tone of the text. They don't publish things they know are not true. That's why I called them generally reliable rather than reputable. I also included a Times of Israel source as something from the other side but also doesn't publish things they know are untrue.

Comment: @JackB al Jazeera reports wrong information about Palestine/Israel routinely.

Comment: This "answer" is entirely speculation that wholly fails to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @IanKemp The BBC info about the 2 month old who starved is quite credible.

Answer (score 6):

Hunger is a bit like old age in that it is often not the direct cause
of death. A 100-year-old gets influenza and dies. Was it the influenza
or the old age? A baby who hasn't eaten in a week gets influenza and
dies. Was it the influenza or the hunger? The point here is that the
number of deaths directly attributable to hunger will be relatively
few, while the number deaths, where hunger is a contributing factor,
will be orders of magnitude larger.

That said, we do have some evidence of deaths due to starvation:

- 2024-02-24, Mahmoud Fattouh, a two-months-old baby [[8](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1761285236770382047)]
- 2024-02-26, Elham Jona, a 17-year-old girl from Al-Tuffa with
  cerebral palsy [[1](https://twitter.com/muhammadshehad2/status/1762098702867394757), [2](https://twitter.com/PALMENA_IC/status/1762081324007879131), [3](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1762149642836300247)]
- 2024-02-27, Anhar Saqr Al-Shanbari, a young girl from Beit Hanoun
  [[4](https://twitter.com/swilkinsonbc/status/1762519645360111912), [5](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1762510137304985843), [6](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1762751944068624450)]
- 2024-02-28, Sahar Al-Zabda, an infant at Kamal Adwan Hospital in
  northern Gaza [[7](https://twitter.com/RamAbdu/status/1762940845970407714), [9](https://twitter.com/EyeonPalestine/status/1763078688860447082)]
- 2024-03-01, Hiba Ziada, an infant at Kamal Adwan Hospital in northern Gaza [[10](https://twitter.com/AlnaouqA/status/1763655027732742282), [11](https://twitter.com/muhammadshehad2/status/1763671572198379742)].
- 2024-03-04, Yazan Al-Kafarna, a 9-year-old boy with cerebral palsy from Beit Hanoun [[13](https://twitter.com/swilkinsonbc/status/1764596079595593936), [14](https://twitter.com/QudsNen/status/1764552007384236401)].

According to [Christian Lindmeier of the WHO](https://twitter.com/UN_News_Centre/status/1763618296358694971) ten children have,
according to Gaza hospital records, starved to death so far. The
reports of starvation deaths are unsurprising given what human rights
organizations have previously reported about food scarcity in
Gaza. Note that this is my **original research** (which I will update),
all sources are from Twitter, and none of the deaths have been
"confirmed" by Western media. Perhaps they never will given the
chaotic situation and short news cycles. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Note that Quds News Network is a propaganda source allegedly affiliated with Hamas.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, there are multiple reports of children starving to death in Gaza.**

---

> Children are dying of starvation in northern Gaza, **the World Health Organization (WHO) chief says.**
> .
> Tedros Adhanom Ghebreyesus said the agency's visits over the weekend to the Al-Awda and Kamal Adwan hospitals were the first since early October.
>
> In a post on social media, he spoke of "grim findings".
>
> A lack of food resulted in the deaths of 10 children and "severe levels of malnutrition", while hospital buildings have been destroyed, he wrote.
>
> The Hamas-run health ministry in Gaza reported on Sunday that at least 15 children had died from malnutrition and dehydration at the Kamal Adwan hospital.
>
> A 16th child died on Sunday at a hospital in the southern city of Rafah, the **Palestinian official news agency Wafa reported** on Monday.

[BBC News - 04 March 2024](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-68471572)

> **Dr Tedros (WHO) reported "severe levels of malnutrition, children dying of starvation,** serious shortages of fuel, food and medical supplies, hospital buildings destroyed" in northern Gaza, where an estimated 300,000 people are living with little food or clean water.
>
> "The lack of food resulted in the deaths of 10 children," he posted on X, formerly known as Twitter.
>
> The visits were the WHO's first in months "despite our efforts to gain more regular access to the north of Gaza", he wrote.
>
> "The situation at Al-Awda Hospital is particularly appalling, as one of the buildings is destroyed," he added.

[BBC News - 04 March 2024](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-68471572)

> The UN warned last week that famine in Gaza was "almost inevitable".
>
> A senior UN aid official warned that at least 576,000 people across the Gaza Strip - one quarter of the population - faced catastrophic levels of food insecurity and one in six children under the age of two in the north were suffering from acute malnutrition.
>
> And **the regional director of the UN's children's agency, Unicef, said "the child deaths we feared are here,** as malnutrition ravages the Gaza Strip".
>
> "These tragic and horrific deaths are man-made, predictable and entirely preventable," Adele Khodr said in a statement on Sunday.

[BBC News - 04 March 2024](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-68471572)

> Gaza’s Health Ministry says “dozens” have been killed and wounded in a “horrific massacre” of aid seekers at the Kuwaiti roundabout in Gaza City.
> **The ministry says at least 15 children have died in the past few days from malnutrition and dehydration at the Kamal Adwan Hospital** in Gaza City hours after the chief of the United Nations Children’s Fund (UNICEF) warned of acute malnutrition.

[Aljazeera - 03 March 2024](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/liveblog/2024/3/3/israels-war-on-gaza-live-every-minute-counts-as-hunger-kills-in-gaza?update=2745162)